# Messaging Middleware Vs RPC and Distributed Databases

Tags: database, messaging, rpc

I would like to know your opinions on advantages and disadvantages of using 
Messaging Middleware vs. RPC and Distributed Databases in a distributed application?

Answer (score 1):

These three are completely different things:

- Message Oriented Middleware (MOM): A subsystem providing (arbitrary) message delivery services between interested systems. Usually providing the ability to change messages' content, route them, log them, guarantee the delivery, etc.
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC): A rather generic term denoting a method of invoking a procedure / method / service residing in a remote process.
- Distributed database: seems quite self-explanatory to me, refer to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database).

Hence it's hard to tell specific (dis)advantages not knowing the actual distributed application better. You could be comparing RPC and MOM. In that case MOM usually is a complete message delivery solution, while RPC is just a technical mean of inter-process communication.

Comment: Ok, point taken! But still think I have a point - so lets me explain.  Take a train control system which involves connectivity between track, software and other hardware equipemnt.  These three technologies could be used for communication between the components or just a Distributed Database(however difficult that might be) But for the sake of argument, the three are possible - if you agree, what are the pros and cons - lets limit MOM to MSMQ in my case.Thanks

Comment: MSMQ is a particular message oriented middleware. Like WebSphere MQ is for example.

Comment: you're not really answering my question, just telling me what you know about these stuff! I mentioned MSMQ(WebSphere MQ) as I intend to use it for this partucular project of mine.

Comment: My point was in disambiguating your question actually. I think you should provide more details on your project to get more help.

Comment: Ah ok, this is a model train control system - which includes track, train, signals all send messages to a central Queue or could use RPC for communication? but for the sake of a general argument I wanted to compare Distributed Dbases as opposed to these two technologies.